# Test metodo de un modelo en Ruby on Rails con rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, test, rspec

Estoy intentando realizar el test del metodo 'is_holder', que verifica que la categoria del afiliado comience con la letra "T". El metodo se encuentra en el modelo de 'affiliates'. He intentado lo siguiente:

Mi modelo tiene el siguiente metodo:

```
 # Verifico que el user sea affiliate titular
 def self.is_holder(id_persona)
   Affiliate.joins(:category).where("id_persona = ?", id_persona).first.category.code[0]=='T'
 end
```

Y mi test es el siguiente:

```
it 'is_holder' do
  affiliate = build(:affiliate)
  affiliate.category.code = "TAEE"
  expect(Affiliate.is_holder(affiliate.id)).to be true   
end
```

El error que me arroja este test es el siguiente:

```
Failure/Error: Affiliate.joins(:category).where("id_persona = ?", id_persona).first.category.code[0]=='T'
 
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `category' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al llamar `build(:affiliate)` solo estás generando una nueva instancia sin haberla guardado en la BD, por lo que deberías llamar a `create(:affiliate)` o llamar a `.save` donde consideres pertinente que debas guardar.
Respecto a tu consulta a la BD:

```
def self.is_holder(id_persona)
  # Algunos detalles:
  #
  # - No es necesario llamar a Affiliate.joins..., porque ya estás
  #   definiendo is_holder como un método de clase, así que es redundante.
  # - Puedes consultar directamente en la BD si el código de la categoría
  #   asociada comienza con T con ILIKE. 
  # - Por último me parece raro que consultes a la base de datos por la
  #   columna `id_persona` cuando en el test estás llamando a affiliate.id,
  #   creo que deberías comparar la variable id_persona que está recibiendo
  #   este método con id, lo cual funciona simplemente llamando a
  #   exists?(id) tal cual está hecho aquí.
  joins(:category).where('categories.code ILIKE ?', 'T%').exists?(id_persona)
  # En caso de que efectivamente la columna de la BD sea id_persona,
  # deberías llamarlo de esta forma
  joins(:category).where('categories.code ILIKE ?', 'T%').exists?(id_persona: id_persona)
end

# Y un detalle anexo, creo que mejor podrías implementar un método que verificase
# directamente en la instancia si comienza con T (la llamarías como
# affiliate.holder?), te ahorrarías hacer las consultas a mano, aparte que
# no necesitarías acceder a la BD si los valores de category ya están
# cargados para la instancia, haciendo tu test mucho más rápido (se
# ahorraría una consulta a la BD ya que en tu test ya le estás dando un
# valor con affiliate.category.code = "TAEE").
def holder?
  category&.code&.starts_with?('T')
end
```

Y por si acaso, cambié de `is_holder` a `holder?` por [convención](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#bool-methods-qmark) de [rubocop](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#bool-methods-prefix), pero puedes dejarlo como tu desees.